# not able to use two dataset on same .aspx.cs page

Tags: c#, asp.net, ado.net

I am using two Datasets on this page 1.DsCountry(in BindCountry())  and 2.DsState(in BindState())  but data from the database is getting filled only in DsCountry not in DsState but when BindCountry() is commented DsState is working.

```
public void BindCountry()
{
    objCountry.SortOn = Convert.ToString(ViewState["SortOn"]);
    objCountry.SortBy = Convert.ToString(ViewState["SortBy"]);
    DataSet DsCountry = objCountry.GetAllCountryDetails();
    ddlCntry.DataSource = DsCountry.Tables[0];
    ddlCntry.DataValueField = "CountryId";
    ddlCntry.DataTextField = "CountryName";
    ddlCntry.DataBind();
}

public void BindState()
{
    objState.CountryId = int.Parse(ddlCntry.SelectedItem.Value);
    objState.StateName = txtState.Text.Trim();
    objState.SortOn = ViewState["SortOnState"].ToString();
    objState.SortBy = ViewState["SortByState"].ToString();
    DataSet DsState = objState.getStates();
    gvState.DataSource = DsState;
    gvState.DataBind();

}
```

Comment: When you comment the bindcountry() method then what value is assigning in this line . objState.CountryId = int.Parse(ddlCntry.SelectedItem.Value);

Comment: When i comment BindCountry() i had to commen that line also otherwise its giving error

Answer (score 0):

In here:

```
public void BindState()
{
    objState.CountryId = int.Parse(ddlCntry.SelectedItem.Value);
    objState.StateName = txtState.Text.Trim();
    objState.SortOn = ViewState["SortOnState"].ToString();
    objState.SortBy = ViewState["SortByState"].ToString();
    DataSet DsState = objState.getStates();
    gvState.DataSource = DsState;
    gvState.DataBind();
}
```

on this line:

```
gvState.DataSource = DsState;
```

if this is a dataset (implies it has multiple tables in it), then you need to specify a specific table you want to bind to, just like in your country method:

```
ddlCntry.DataSource = DsCountry.Tables[0];
```

will become this:

```
gvState.DataSource = DsState.Tables[0];
```

Assuming you return only one table in the dataset.

otherwise its like: go get me something I do not know what. :)

Comment: its not that problem....i checked it in debugging mode,table n the DsState is not getting filled with the data from the database just its getting the column names

Comment: if it returns only column names, then maybe table in the db is empty?

Comment: when i run my friends project with same databse its working fine

Answer (score 0):

Your BindState Code should be like this

public void BindState()
{

```
objState.CountryId = int.Parse(ddlCntry.SelectedItem.Value);
objState.StateName = txtState.Text.Trim();
objState.SortOn = ViewState["SortOnState"].ToString();
objState.SortBy = ViewState["SortByState"].ToString();
DataSet DsState = objState.getStates();
gvState.DataSource = DsState.Tables[0];
gvState.DataBind();
```

}

You can apply more than 1 dataset in 1 page.

Comment: I have tried it.its not that problem....i checked it in debugging mode,table in the DsState is not getting filled with the data from the database just its getting the column names